# Blocking auth triggers in cloud functions for firebase second generation

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, triggers

[image]
I am referring this https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/auth-blocking-events documentation to implement Blocking auth triggers using 2nd generation cloud function for firebase,
I have created and deployed functions but the problem is that, while registering the triggers under the Blocking functions tab in the Firebase Authentication console, It does not shows that deployed triggers (beforeUserSignedIn, beforeUserCreated) for registering.

Below is my code,

```
import functions from 'firebase-functions/v2'
import admin from 'firebase-admin'
import { beforeUserCreated, beforeUserSignedIn } from 'firebase-functions/v2/identity'

import serviceKey from './serviceKey.json' assert {type: 'json'}

admin.initializeApp(serviceKey)


export const beforecreated = beforeUserCreated((event) => {
    console.log("EVENT DATA FOR AUTH beforecreated....", event.data)
    return;
});

export const beforesignedin = beforeUserSignedIn((event) => {
    console.log("EVENT DATA FOR AUTH beforesignedin....",event.data)
});
```

I have tried Blocking auth triggers for first-generation cloud functions for firebase and it's working fine, and also I can register that blocking auth triggers. But this is not working for the second generation cloud function for firebase.

Comment: Had a similar problem, fixed it by updating to the latest version of `firebase-tools`, can you try that?

Comment: Yes, I have tried but not working. Can you explain how to do it?

Comment: run `npm i -g firebase-tools` and try deploying your functions again. The firebase console has a bug showing if the function is connected, I reached out to them yesterday but you can confirm if your function is working still by creating a new user

Comment: Appears to still be an issue. Updating `firebase-tools` didn't solve. However, despite the big red box warning that users are "being blocked from authenticating your application," everything is working as it should. I see events captured in the logs. Scary UI bug, but everything is OK. For now, anyway.